# Convert text to HTML based on pattern matching in Java

Tags: java, html, formatting

I am trying to develop tool in which I can covert simple text to HTML format as given in below examples.

**1. Java :** I want to convert below text into html in a such way so that it will look beautiful colorful **java** code on browser 
`&&&java
public static void main(String[] arg){
  System.out.println("Hello from java");
}
&&&`

**2. XML :** I want to convert below text into html in a such way so that it will look beautiful colorful **xml** code on browser 
`&&&xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
&&&`

**3. JS :** I want to convert below text into html in a such way so that it will look beautiful colorful **javascript** code on browser 
`&&&js<BR>
MyStore.load('http://this/is/test/json.json',function(res,isError){
  Console.log(res);
});
&&&`

I am using pattern like `&&&java` and `&&&xml` and `&&&js` to indicate that below  script is for java, xml or java script accordingly.

This would require basically two sub-tasks.

1. To detect text for which we need to replace html code.

   - Does regular expression work here? if yes, how? any small example?
2. Replace right html/css code after detecting the part of text for which we need to replace.

   - Is there any library/tool/frameworks in java which will work for me?
   - I know the `jsoup` library for HTML parsing, but is this possible with it? if yes, how?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @downvoter, whenever you down vote, you should describe `why`. Please.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called Java2HTML, you can download it from [here](http://www.vaegar.f9.co.uk/java2html//download.html) and decompile it.